# How to re-render a full page with <Link> tag in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router-dom

please help me about a problem i had with Link in react-router-dom like this:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        const theEle = document.getElementById("id-of-div");
        const eleTop = theEle.offsetTop;
        const eleBottom = eleTop + theEle.offsetHeight;
        console.log("the element of new page", eleTop, eleBottom)
    });
```

So when i put the above script in page X, in page Y i have an

```
<a href='/x'>Link to page X<a>
```

if i clicked it in page Y then of course you will go to page X and scroll the mouse, window detect the mouse scroll and log out the result

But if i used a Link tag in react-router-dom then there would be an error saying can't get offsetTop of 'id-of-div'

```
<Link to='/x'>Link to page X</Link>
```

I wonder is there a way to force Link to do the job without using an a tag, because i really don't want the user re-render page x everytimes they go from page Y to X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously if you render other page, the `id-of-div` is not rendered anymore (it gets removed from the DOM) so actually you can't check it's `offsetTop`.

One of the solutions would be to check inside if the `id-of-div` exists:

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    const theEle = document.getElementById("id-of-div");
    if (theEle) {
       const eleTop = theEle.offsetTop;
       const eleBottom = eleTop + theEle.offsetHeight;
       console.log("the element of new page", eleTop, eleBottom);
    }
});
```

However more flexible solution would be to connect the listener not with the `window`, but to the parent wrapper in that page where `x`. But keep in mind that it can be impossible in particular cases (depends on your components structure).

Comment: thank you for your answer, you are correct to check whether element is existed before get it offset. is there another ways to detect the scroll action beside of the window listener ?